# How to create an array of previously retrieved posts from an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

Here is the problem I am working on. 
Attached is an index.html.

Implement the next and previous buttons to navigate to next/previous posts from the API provider (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com).

Create a new tag that displays the current post ID.

Bonus points: Create a new array to store all of the previously retrieved posts, and display them in a list.
The API is from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, so you don't need to implement that. A jsfiddle would be immensely appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title>Vue Test</title>
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  <div>
    <span>{{post.title}}</span>
  </div>
  <button v-on:click="previousPost">Previous Post</button> <!-- // new vue      directive - v-on:click, also  -->
  <button v-on:click="nextPost">Next Post</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<script
       src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
       integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
       ***emphasized text***crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Welcome to Vue!',
    post: {},
    page: 1
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getPost()
  },
  methods: {
    nextPost: function() {

       this.page = this.page + 1 


      this.getPost()






      // Implement me
    },
    previousPost: function() {
      // Implement me

       this.page = this.page - 1

      this.getPost()



    },
    getPost: function() {
      var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

      $.ajax({
        url: root + '/posts/' + this.page,
        method: 'GET'
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.post = data;
      });
    }
  }
})
</script>

<style>
  /* Add any additional styles here */
  body {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  div {
    margin: 12px 0;
  }

</style>
```

I would also like to know what is meant by the post id over there. I have completed one task which shows the next and previous posts, but the other two tasks I am a little confused.

Comment: A jsfiddle would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: I can mail you the html file because I am not able to run it on jsfiddle because of using other frameworks and stuff. you can run the file in your browser. May I get your email?

Comment: If that is the case, put it in a ftp / shared location